# Custom record to json key conversion in Haskell using Aeson library

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

Below code does not work for me. Can anyone explain how to solve and avoid below kind of errors in Haskell

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

module Test where

import GHC.Generics
import Data.Aeson.Types
import Data.Aeson

data Person = Person { personId :: Int , personName :: String} deriving (Show, Generic)

instance ToJSON Person where
    toJson p = [
            "id" .= personId p,
            "name" .= personName p
        ]

instance FromJSON Person
```

I am getting following error. I am not able to figure out the issue here.

```
Prelude> :load src/User/Test
[1 of 1] Compiling Test             ( src\User\Test.hs, interpreted )

src\User\Test.hs:13:5: error:
    `toJson' is not a (visible) method of class `ToJSON'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: I believe this is a simple typo it should be `toJSON` instead of `toJson`

Comment: Thanks. I didn't notice it . However, the error is so confusing . Coming from OOP I thought "not visible" means the method is not exposed out of module .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the method is `toJSON`, not `toJson`. Identifiers are case-sensitive in Haskell. You can find this in the [`aeson` documentation for the `ToJSON` class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.2.3.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#t:ToJSON).